# How to split resulted records when inserting them into source destination SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package, between to servers (a MS SQL Server 2008 R2 and a Teradata server) which takes some data from one table from one server and sends it to the destination server via an ADO.Net connection, to another table and was deployed as a daily ran Sql Server Agent Job.
   Bottom line is that due to the huge amount of the lines processed from one server and to the destination table, I have to "split" the process some how.
   My question is as an concept how can this thing be done? Should I create another table in which to mark what was already inserted? Is there something already build in the SSIS which can help me to force the data flow task to send "bursts" of data into destination? Maybe specify the number of rows per "burst"?

Looking forward to your responses,

Comment: Which is the source? SQL Server or Teradata? Yes it may be necessary to use CDC of some kind to reduce the records sent. There are many solutions to implement CDC. Please add the version of SQL Server also.

Comment: If you are using `ADO.net destination` then u can check [Bulk Insert option](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2009/11/12/something-new-for-ssis-in-sql-server-2008-r2-november-ctp.aspx) or using `OLEDB destination` you can specify the `rows per batch`

Comment: Hello, First of all thanks for the quick response. The Sql Server 2008 R2 is the source server and the teradata is the destination Server. As for an Ole.DB destination it's not valid solution. A Teradata destination cannot be achieved with Ole.DB. Only with Ado.net or Attunity.